# Talend (7.0.1) - Guess Schema error - org.apache.thrift.TAppliccationexception:Required field 'client_protocol' is unset

Tags: bigdata, talend

I am getting below error while designing and running job in Talend(i.e. when i hit Guess Schema button in tHiveInput component). I have tried all the options but I am unable to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Talend version : 7.0.1
OS : RHEL 7

[image: Talend Job flow]

ERROR jdbc.HiveConnection: Error opening session
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:168)
    at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:155)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:680)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:200)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at org.talend.metadata.managment.connection.manager.HiveConnectionManager$1.call(HiveConnectionManager.java:259)
    at org.talend.metadata.managment.connection.manager.HiveConnectionManager$1.call(HiveConnectionManager.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/09/14 13:48:00 WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to :
ERROR: 
java.sql.SQLException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://:/: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://:/: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000, use:database=default})

Comment: FYI .. I masked host and port info

Comment: can someone help me on this please ?